# Login after Ubuntu Upgrade - no password set previously

Tags: login, password

Before upgrading from 16.10 to 17.10 I had set no password and configured the system to login automatically (So not even a prompt would appear on which I'd have had to press enter).
After the upgrade I'm stuck at the starting screen, where I can select the users, which there is only one of.
When I click on myself, the screen changes shades of black for 2 seconds or so and returns to the same login menu. When I click on "Not listed here" and manually enter that same user name, the same happens (I'm not prompted for a password).
I can login via the console, though. (Ctrl+Alt+F...) I've restarted my computer from there (sudo shutdown), but I was shown that same welcome screen the next time.
How can I make the system "log in GUI wise" after the next boot or is there any other trick?

Comment: entering passwd in the console helped, but it turns out that wasn't the problem after all, and I'm still thrown back to the login menu after I've correctly entered the new password

Comment: Have a look at [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) or one of the many similarly named questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)